# Apache cordova - how to open native app for Google play or Itunes?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, google-play, itunes

I would to implement into my Cordova app following feature:

If i click on button in app app open native app with google play or iTunes with predefined URL to all my apps.

I don't want to use inApp browser, I would like to open native app for market on given platform.

**Is any plugin for this? Or how i can do this?**

**Im using:**

- Cordova
- Ionic

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: did you find the sotuion ?

Answer (score 12):

Is it possible using inapp browser plugin with _system param:

**window.open("market://details?id=com.your.app", "_system");**

```
$scope.rateApplication = function () {
            var platform = device.platform;
            switch(platform.toLowerCase()) {
                case "android":
                    window.open("market://details?id=com.your.app", "_system");
                    break;
                case "ios":
                    window.open("itunes_url", "_system");
                    break;
            }
        },
```